# Thumbor: IOError: decoder jpeg not available

Tags: python, image, thumbor

I'm working for VTNC, trying to run the **Thumbor**'s **Getting Started** first sample, but it returns me this error:

```
(thumbor)mac:thumbor pzanetti631$ thumbor
2014-01-29 13:49:32 thumbor:ERROR Could not save as improved image, consider to increase       ImageFile.MAXBLOCK
Traceback (most recent call last):
File ".../sandbox/thumbor/lib/python2.7/site-packages/thumbor/engines/pil.py", line 137, in read
self.image.save(img_buffer, FORMATS[ext], **options)
File ".../sandbox/thumbor/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 1420, in save
self.load()
File ".../sandbox/thumbor/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PIL/ImageFile.py", line 193, in load
d = Image._getdecoder(self.mode, d, a, self.decoderconfig)
File ".../sandbox/thumbor/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 356, in _getdecoder
raise IOError("decoder %s not available" % decoder_name)
IOError: decoder jpeg not available
2014-01-29 13:49:32 thumbor:ERROR ERROR: Traceback (most recent call last):
File ".../sandbox/thumbor/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tornado/web.py", line 1115, in _stack_context_handle_exception
raise_exc_info((type, value, traceback))
File ".../sandbox/thumbor/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tornado/stack_context.py", line 302, in wrapped
ret = fn(*args, **kwargs)
File ".../sandbox/thumbor/lib/python2.7/site-packages/thumbor/loaders/http_loader.py", line 49, in return_contents
callback(response.body)
File ".../sandbox/thumbor/lib/python2.7/site-packages/thumbor/handlers/__init__.py", line 298, in handle_loader_loaded
buffer = engine.read()
File ".../sandbox/thumbor/lib/python2.7/site-packages/thumbor/engines/pil.py", line 140, in read
self.image.save(img_buffer, FORMATS[ext])
File ".../sandbox/thumbor/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 1420, in save
self.load()
File ".../sandbox/thumbor/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PIL/ImageFile.py", line 193, in load
d = Image._getdecoder(self.mode, d, a, self.decoderconfig)
File ".../sandbox/thumbor/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 356, in _getdecoder
raise IOError("decoder %s not available" % decoder_name)
IOError: decoder jpeg not available

2014-01-29 13:49:32 tornado.access:ERROR 500 GET /unsafe/300x0/http://www.waterfalls.hamilton.ca/images/Waterfall_Collage_home_sm1.jpg (127.0.0.1) 2077.94ms
```

ds

I'm on Mac and I've installed it via pip, following the [Documentation](https://github.com/globocom/thumbor/wiki). And it says that PIL is installed by default...

How can I fix this?

Here is my `pip freeze` output:

```
(thumbor)mac:thumbor pzanetti631$ pip freeze
Pillow==2.1.0
derpconf==0.4.9
pycrypto==2.6.1
pycurl==7.19.3
python-magic==0.4.6
six==1.5.2
thumbor==3.15.0
tornado==3.1.1
wsgiref==0.1.2
```

Cheers,

-- Paulo Zanetti

Comment: Sounds like `PIL` was installed without JPEG support. Can't you reinstall PIL or create a `virtualenv` around your program?

Comment: @Krumelur I'm already under a virtualenv, and cannot remove/install PIL...

Answer (score 3):

Here's how I (oddly) solve the problem:

**1)** After install **Thumbor**, remove **Pillow** (as of today, it install version `2.1.0`);

**2)** (Re)install **Pillow** (as of today, it will install version `2.3.0`); and

**3)** After that, (re)install **Thumbor**.

Answer (score 0):

That's really odd. I'm one of the committers in thumbor. It should work with pillow 2.1.0. Do you have PIL installed? Pillow won't work with PIL installed.

Sorry for any issues you have. Please do create an issue in the project next time you get stuck!

Cheers,
Bernardo Heynemann